# If the Earth's axial tilt increased, how much farther would the Earth need to be to have the same climate, if possible?

Tags: axial-tilt

Changing the axial tilt of the Earth affects the seasons/temperatures of the Earth. But if we increased the axial tilt of the Earth, could we preserve the same climate by moving the Earth farther away from the Sun? Or by changing the orbit in some way? What would the calculation for this look like?

Related:

- [Would the tropic and arctic climate bands switch if the Earth's axial tilt changed to 60 degrees?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/110254/would-the-tropic-and-arctic-climate-bands-switch-if-the-earths-axial-tilt-chang)
- [How would a larger axial tilt affect the Earth's climate?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25193/how-would-a-larger-axial-tilt-affect-the-earths-climate)
- https://www.quora.com/What-if-earths-tilt-was-50-degrees
- https://www.quora.com/What-would-climate-be-like-if-earths-axial-tilt-is-35-degrees

Comment: Welcome to World building, it is usually suggested that you wait 24 hours before accepting an answer to allow time for other time zones to submit an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**

Axial tilt affects how extreme the difference is between summer and winter. Fiddling with the orbit affects the *overall* climate. Changes to one cannot cancel out changes to the other.

Comment: Sounds like you're considering just increasing the distance of he orbit without changing the eccentricity of the orbit.

Comment: Changing the eccentricity might be able to offset the changes for *one* hemisphere, but not both.